# Problem with using filter function to remove missing values from a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, na

I am required to remove all observations where at least one of these variables `Loading Date`, `year of built`, `vessel type` and `cargo size` contain missing values.

```
    anyNA(CW_data$`Loading Date`) #result is FALSE, which means there aren't missing values
    anyNA(CW_data$`Year Built`) #result is TRUE, there are missing values
    anyNA(CW_data$`Vessel Type`)#result is TRUE, there are missing values
    anyNA(CW_data$`Cargo Size`)#result is TRUE, there are missing values

    CW_data_noNA <- filter(CW_data, is.na('Year Built')==FALSE |
                   is.na('Vessel Type'==FALSE)|
                   is.na('Cargo Size')==FALSE |
                     is.na('Loading Date') == FALSE)
```

I tried with the above code, but the resulting dataset is identical to the original one. May someone explain what I am doing wrong? many thanks, LMC

Comment: `is.na(\`Year Built\`)` rather than `is.na('Year Built')` would work fine. Though is.na returns a logical value, though checking `is.na(x) == FALSE` is checking `FALSE == FALSE` or `TRUE == FALSE`, so you can just use `!is.na(x)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter_at`:

```
CW_data_noNA <- filter_at(CW_data, vars('Year Built', 'Vessel Type', 'Cargo Size', 'Loading Date'), 
                            all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

If you want use `filter` instead you can do this:

```
CW_data_noNA <- CW_data %>% 
                 filter(!is.na('Year Built'), !is.na('Vessel Type'),
                        !is.na('Cargo Size'), !is.na('Loading Date'))
```

This keeps all rows where none of the four columns is `NA`.
Inside `filter` various conditions are always concatenated using `&`.

If you instead want to keep those row where not all four columns are `NA` simultaneously use:

```
W_data %>% 
   filter(!is.na('Year Built') | !is.na('Vessel Type') |
          !is.na('Cargo Size') | is.na('Loading Date'))
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to accomplish it with filter()? I'm sorry but I'm a beginner with r

Comment: Actually with the second code (the one with filter) doesn't work! it gives me the original dataset.

Comment: this means that there is not a single row where all of the four columns are `NA`.

Comment: The problem is that I am required to remove all the rows with AT LEAST one of those variables containing missing values. 
Anyways the one you sent me with filter_at works, which means it is possible to reduce the dataset. I was just wondering how to do that with just the filter() function.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood the question and updated my answer

Comment: maybe you can post a sample of your data inside your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `filter` you can do like this:

```
CW_data_noNA <- CW_data %>% 
    filter(!is.na(`Year Built`) & !is.na(`Vessel Type`) &
           !is.na(`Cargo Size`) & !is.na(`Loading Date`)
           )
```

When you have strange names in columns you need to use backticks ``. In general, I think it's better to avoid whitespaces for column names.

Regarding the code you provided, `is.na` already returns a logical, so you can use the `!is.na` instead of `is.na() == FALSE`. The pipe `%>%` also allows you to get a cleaner code!

Next time, try providing a reproducible example with your data or some sample data for better understanding.

Comment: OK, I'll try with backticks! maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work. Anyways I am required to eliminate all the rows with AT LEAST a variable containing NA. should I substitute & with | ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice about data, I'm new and I din't realize it was that important.

Comment: @LMC I think with `&` you'll keep rows that have all non-NA values (similar to the `filter_at` solution), but I could be wrong. No problem about the data, it's just intended to make it easier for people to understand what they're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

This may work your situation

```
CW_data_noNA <- CW_data %>% drop_na()
```